# Not getting color in R charts

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plyr

I am trying to get some basic bar graphs for a few variables. 
While running few codes, I am getting the output graphs as desired. But for some, the output is not proper and the graphs are mono-color(gray).
Unable to figure out what error it is. I have attached the output for the 2nd graph.
Kindly let me know where I am going wrong. I am pretty new to R programming.

The data set MD loooks like this

```
State   Year        Desc        Amt
TN      2014        Won     158
OK      2015        Lost    175
WA      2013        Won     145 
OG      2015        Lost    174
IL      2014        Won     165

library(ggplot2)

#Metric for AB */
AB <- ddply(MD,c("State","Year", "Desc"),
            function (MD){data.frame(  Total_Lo=nrow(MD), Total_Amt=sum(MD$Lo_Amt), Avg_Amt=mean(MD$Lo_Amt))})  


#Loan Amount metric for States
A <-ddply(AB,c("State", "Desc"), 
          function(AB){data.frame(Number_A=sum(AB$Total_Lo),Total_Amt_A=sum(AB$Total_Amt),  Avg_Amt_A=sum(AB$Total_Amt)/sum(AB$Total_Lo))})

 #Loan Amount Metric for Years
B <-ddply(AB,c("Year" , "Desc"),
          function(AB){data.frame(Number_B=sum(AB$Total_Lo),Total_B=sum(AB$Total_Amt),Avg_B=sum(AB$Total_Amt)/sum(AB$Total_Lo))})

#Getting proper output
qplot(State, data = A, 
      fill=State, geom = "bar",  
      weight=Total_Amt_,ylab="Total Amount", 
      main = "Total  Amount for all ")

#Getting output but no color
qplot(Year, data = B, fill=_Year, 
      geom = "bar",weight=Number_B,ylab="Total Count ", 
      main = " Number by Year") 

#No proper output
qplot(State, data = AB, fill=Year, 
      geom = "bar",weight=Total_Number_Lo, 
      ylab="Total Number", main = "Number each state ")
```

Comment: Not reproducible, object `MD` is missing. Use `dput(MD)` and paste the result

Comment: I still can't reproduce the last plot, and I had to fix some code. Read about making a [great, reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1261281)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a reference to the `fill` aesthetic and then assign a color to it via `scale_fill_manual`:

```
qplot(Year, data = B, fill='FILL_AES', 
      geom = "bar",weight=Number_B,ylab="Total Count ", 
      main = " Number by Year") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('FILL_AES' = 'blue'))
```

---

Note that `qplot` is not intended to create fully fledged graphs, it's just for fast prototyping and testing. If you need to customize your graph pls use and learn `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(B, aes(x = Year, y = Number_B)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'blue') +
  ggtitle('Number by year')
```